# Why cloudflare blocking access site when user enter thai language as input

Tags: asp.net, cloudflare, thai

We are working on exam based website. Admin will enter all questions required for exam. It need to support multiple languages. When we to submit question in thai language text cloudfare blocking access to server. This is happening when we enter thai language text only. Please suggest resolution steps.
[image]

Comment: Do you have WAF (Web Application Firewall) enabled? This is not an available feature in free-tier cloudflare.

Comment: @drussey  WAF enabled . Is it reason for this problem ?

Comment: Do the waf "activity logs" in the Cloudflare firewall panel give any indication which rule is being triggered when this block is happening?

Comment: @drussey the following is log for this error. It is happening to thai  language only.            {
"key":"anomaly_score",
"value":"40"
},
{
"key":"sqli_score",
"value":"14"
},
{
"key":"xss_score",
"value":"15"
}

Comment: It looks like you may want to lower your OWASP rule sensitivity to let these requests through, or perhaps change from "block" to "challenge" on the action to take on OWASP rules.

Comment: I have disabled cloudfare firewall to website. Then it's working